# NSSearchField either hangs or has no search/clear buttons

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit, nssearchfield

So I've got a bunch of `NSSearchField` instances in my app.

However, one of them does neither feature the clear (*x*) button nor the magnifier glass.

Turns out **the alignment was set to center**.

Changing it to left-align or back to the default ('---') brings back the 'x' and magnifier - but now the app hangs for a couple of seconds when starting to enter text into the search field, nothing seems to happen.

Another effect:

- **Center Align**: Focus ring appears when activating the control
- **Left Align**: No Focus ring when clicking into the control, characters either don't show up at all or only after a significant delay (2-5s)

Anybody seeing something similar?

Any suggestions how to get a plain `NSSearchField` working..?

---

***Note #1 (5/11)***

Further investigations with Instruments show nothing so far, not even some Auto Layout screw up (i.e. the spikes you see when a bug in the constraints engine causes the app to apparently hang).

The app just doesn't repsond.

Comment: Remove it and add a new one? Xcode is buggy.

Comment: Tried that, same effect.

Comment: Is the search field somehow connected?

Comment: I've had both - one with outlets, bindings and others w/o anything, just dropped in the views from the IB palette. Seems to revolve around the alignment options: changing them breaks the search field, default options leave me w/o cancel/search icons :-/

Comment: When you enter text in a searchfield and it triggers a filter, it can take some time to filter the data.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense that is takes ~100-1000x longer when the formatting is left aligned, right?

Comment: Something is wrong. What happens when you create a new simple Xcode project and add a search field?